# Pandas script not removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm new to Pandas and am attempting to remove some unnecessary columns  and then drop the duplicate records. The first part of the script works as the columns are removed. However, the script is not executing the second portion of the task as there are plenty of duplicates remaining. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
f =pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
    keep_col =['ZIP5','STATE CODE','STATE','COUNTY CODE','COUNTY NAME','CBSA CODE','CBSA TITLE','CBSA LSAD','METRO DIVISION CODE','METRO DIVISION TITLE','METRO DIVISION LSAD','CSA CODE','CSA TITLE','CSA LSAD']
    new_f = f[keep_col]
    new_f.drop_duplicates()
    new_f.to_csv("newfile.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign back or pass `inplace=True`:

```
new_f = new_f.drop_duplicates()
```

or

```
new_f.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) state this, also in general nearly all pandas ops return a copy, most support `inplace` param so you need to either assign back to overwrite or pass `inplace=true` where supported.